# How to get field value of selected Row Devexpress GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I use a DevexpressGridView to display all `TOPIC (id,title,content)`

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gv" runat="server"
OnSelectionChanged="gv_SelectionChanged" >
```

I have grid_SelectionChanged event:

```
protected void gv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int id= selected row...???; //how can I get the value of selected row
        string sql = "select * from TOPIC where idTOPIC="+id;
        DataTable topic = l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
        TextBox1.Text = topic.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    }
```

...

It seems `gv.SelectedRow` method isn't exist in DevGridview.

As recommended, I've tried with `FocusedRowIndex` method, but I really dont know the right syntax to get the value of selected row.

Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answere here after a long time searching google:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q347704

Use the [ASPxGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) method get selected row values on the server side.

Answer (score 8):

Changing the selection is different from changing the focused row. See the documentation for [`Selection`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_Selectiontopic) for the difference between the two.

You can use [`gv.GetSelectedFieldValues`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) to get the rows which are selected.

```
var ids = gv.GetSelectedFieldValues("id");
foreach( var id in ids )
    DoSomethingWithObject(id);
```

You should handle the [`FocusedRowChanged`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FocusedRowChangedtopic) event if you're interested in the focused row.

You can use the `FocusedRowIndex` value to index the rows of `gv.DataSource`, for example:

```
DataTable ds = (DataTable)gv.DataSource;
var id = ds.Rows[gv.FocusedRowIndex]["id"];
```

or you can use [`var id = gv.GetRowValues(gv.FocusedRowIndex, "id")`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowValuestopic).

Comment: gv.Selection give back the row position, is that right? What thing I can do with the position of row? I mean, I have to do what to get the value? Can you tell me some detail? It is so hard for me to work with DevexpressGridView

Comment: There are a lot of quirks when working with DevExpress grids, one of them being that it's a little tricky to get the values of the cells in the grid, mainly because the `DataSource` isn't strongly typed. I have updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get selected data row as

```
int rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
   if (rowHandle != DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
   {
    return this.gridView1.GetDataRow(rowHandle);
   }
```

This would return DataRow

Please note this is when I am using Devexpress gridControl in WinForms

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only ID field value you can use this

```
int id =  Convert.ToInt32(gv.GetRowValues(gv.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString());
```

if you have an object you can use this

```
Personels selectedPersonel = gv.GetRow(gv.FocusedRowIndex) as Personels;
```

and get value method is

```
int ID = selectedPersonel.ID;
```