# Reading Specific Part of List Row

Tags: c#, object

I have an object list in a class library, I want to access a single part of the list which contains pricing and save it to a decimal property.

Below is the list being created just for context.

```
OrderItem ord = new OrderItem();

if (Quantity <= 0){ Quantity = 1; }

ord.ProductName = Product;
ord.Quantity = Quantity;
ord.LatestPrice = Price;
ord.TotalOrder = AddItems(Price, Quantity);
shopping.Add(ord);
```

The list gets displayed in a list box as well but I to take all the final decimals and create a total cost.

```
ShoppingListBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (OrderItem Product in shopping)
{
ShoppingListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-30}", Product.ProductName) + string.Format("{0,2}",Product.Quantity.ToString()) + string.Format("{0,15:C2}",Product.LatestPrice) + string.Format("{0,18:C2}",Product.TotalOrder) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I've looked at this for a while now and tried to avoid it for as much time as I can. I thought this post may have held my answers but only contains object arrays. [Previous Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206676/how-to-get-single-value-of-listobject)

Comment: do you need to sum all TotalOrder values (from OrderItem objects) to get total cost of shopping cart?

Comment: Yeah, once the total is calculated it's moved to a text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate total cost with LINQ method easily:

```
decimal totalCost = shopping.Sum(orderItem => orderItem.TotalOrder);
```

It will basically iterate over the shopping collection and sum `TotalOrder` properties.

With that information you can use it and display it wherever you want

Comment: Brilliant thank you, been stuck on this for away too long :)